# Why resolution is not important for pre-trained models

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, pre-training, residual-networks

As far as I understand (and even successfully applied in Kaggle competition), it's possible to feed images of any resolution into the pre-trained model (e.g. ResNet34).
But I do not understand, why it works. My logic, is that the same 3x3 convolutional filter can capture completely different features from 255x255 and 1024x1024 image. For example (a bit exaggerated to show the point), if on 32x32 image 3x3 piece can be already a face, then on 1024x1024 image 3x3 piece is just a horizontal line. What do I miss?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "possible" in the sense that you can do it, but it might not necessarily work well. If you train on only small images and then test on huge images, I would expect results which are not the best. Of course, it will still somewhat work -- there may be some trained-in scale invariance from the fact that images are taken from different distances and focal lengths.

Comment: Hm, the "scale invariance" things really makes sense. I haven't thought about that.

Comment: But in general, as far as I know, it is quite a common practice to take an Imagenet pre-trained model (which was trained on 224x224) and apply transfer learning to the images with better resolution, say 512 or 1024 (maybe with a bit of fine-tuning), and it works well in the end. I mean better, than if we would resize our images from 512/1024 to 224.
Can just "scale invariance" explain that?

Comment: @Bi0max fine-tuning the model changes lets the model adapt to the new image size, so it's not too surprising that you can get good results after that.